# How can I erase elements from a std::set in reverse (from the end until a lower_bounds)

Tags: c++

So I need to erase elements from a std::set in a particular order, doing something with the first.

so if I had a set containing `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` and my I wanted to go until `4`, I need to:

```
doSomething(6);
erase(6);
doSomething(5);
erase(5);
doSomething(4);
erase(4);
```

I have the following code that does not work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

void doSomething(int value) {
    std::cout << value << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::set<int> s = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

    auto beginIt = s.end();
    auto endIt = s.lower_bound(4);
    auto rbegin = std::make_reverse_iterator(beginIt);
    auto rend = std::make_reverse_iterator(endIt);

    for (auto it = rbegin; it != rend;) {
        doSomething(*it);
        s.erase(std::next(it).base());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think the issue is that it erasing the end iterator then keeps going util it crashes.

How can I get this to work.

godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/KvaGWhr4G

Comment: why do you want to erase in the loop rather than after the loop?

Comment: well, my example is a bit simplified of what I actually want to do.. the erasing is optional based on the result of doSomething()

Comment: "My example is a bit simplified of what I actually want to do" is an indicator that this might be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I didn't want to paste in the whole code base, but the example is exactly what I want to do.. just trying to explain "why"

Comment: I'd call `rend()` on each iteration.

Comment: @user1095108 But OP doesn't want to erase until the start, but until specific element.

Comment: actually, calling `rend()` each iteration works, as in I recreate the `rend` each iteration...
`for (auto it = rbegin; it != std::make_reverse_iterator(s.lower_bound(4));) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of doing what you want is to getting your end iterator each time.

```
for (auto it = rbegin; it != std::make_reverse_iterator(s.lower_bound(4));) {
        doSomething(*it);
        s.erase(std::next(it).base());
    }
```

Now let's see why you initial code didn't work.

In set, the iterators are not invalidated after erasing an element, **EXCEPT** for the iterator that was pointing to the erased element.

Now let's see what happened in the last iteration when you remove `4`.

When dereferencing the `rend`, we will see that it points to `3`. However, the base of `rend` points to `4`. And after removal of `4`, the base of `rend` has been invalidated. So your program had Undefined behavior.

To understand why getting end iterator at every iteration works, we have to understand that during the program the base of `it` is always `s.end()`. And at the last step, when we call `s.lower_bound(4)`, we get `s.end()`. Hence, the condition for exiting the loop is satisfied.

Comment: yeah, this does work, and thank you for the explanation! I guess the downside of this is that the time complexity takes a hit, but I don't see a way around this... maybe I only update the `rend` iterator after erasing the `4`

Comment: It depends on how many elements you have in your set. I think time complexity won't increase substantially when doing this.